# No data going into variables, help please? iPhone iOS - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hey everyone, I'm trying to take values from global variables and put them into an email, I'll include my source code, and the error messages. Thanks in advance!

```
MFMailComposeViewController *compose = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
compose.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[compose setSubject:@"Float Plan for my Boat Trip"];
[compose setCcRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"towboat911@gmail.com"]];

NSString *emailFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email_en_US.html"];
NSString *emailFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: emailFileName];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:emailFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PERSON//" withString:@"person"];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//POB//" withString:pob];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PHONE//" withString:phone];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//MEDICAL//" withString:medical];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//DEPART//" withString:depart];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//LEFT//" withString:left];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//ARRIVAL//" withString:arrive];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//DESTINATION//" withString:destination];


body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//VESSELNAME//" withString:vessel_name];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//BUILDERMAKE//" withString:builder_make];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//LENGTH//" withString:length];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//HULLCOLOUR//" withString:colour];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//NUMBER//" withString:number];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//POWER//" withString:power];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//RIG//" withString:rig];


NSString *emailBody = body;
[compose setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

compose.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

[self presentModalViewController:compose animated:YES];
[compose release];
```

and here is the errors that im getting in the console, the instant i press the email click event

```
2011-02-28 18:26:34.595 Tow Boat 911[35121:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:]: nil argument'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00f6abe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00d5f5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00f23628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f2359a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
4   Foundation                          0x0004f3c0 -[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:] + 123
5   Foundation                          0x0004f33e -[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:] + 99
6   Tow Boat 911                        0x00001ec5 -[FloatPlan email:] + 477
7   UIKit                               0x002b8a6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
8   UIKit                               0x003471b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
9   UIKit                               0x00349647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
10  UIKit                               0x00348438 -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 277
11  UIKit                               0x002dd025 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 395
12  UIKit                               0x002be37a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
13  UIKit                               0x002c3732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
14  GraphicsServices                    0x01781a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00f4c064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00eac6f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00ea9983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00ea9240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00ea9161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
20  GraphicsServices                    0x01780268 GSEventRunModal + 217
21  GraphicsServices                    0x0178032d GSEventRun + 115
22  UIKit                               0x002c742e UIApplicationMain + 1160
23  Tow Boat 911                        0x00001a8c main + 102
24  Tow Boat 911                        0x00001a1d start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
(gdb)
```

Comment: You might want to consider using an `NSMutableString` and performing the edits to the string in-place, because `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` creates a new string object each time it is called.

Comment: Where do you define the strings you use as replacements (pob, phone, medical, depart ...)? If these are nil, you could get the exception above.

Answer (score 4):

One of your globals is nil. In XCode in the "Run" menu, you can enable the option "Stop on Objective-C Exceptions" and the debugger will stop when the exception is thrown. You can then use the appropriate dropdowns in XCode find out exactly which line is causing the problem.